# Additions to MathJax/mhchem: Cancel, Broken Arrows; SI units

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

I think sometimes it is necessary to show, that a reaction does not take place, therefore a broken arrow would be a nice thing to have. I played a little in the sandbox and found a somewhat working solution.

The fist solution requires a package, that is in the repository of MathJax, but not yet activated. therefore it has to be included via `\require{cancel}`. My first request is to activate it permanently on the site. Sometimes I would like to show that units cancel, etc.:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
n&=c\cdot V\\
n&=1~\mathrm{\frac{mol}{\cancel{L}}}\cdot 1~\cancel{\mathrm{L}}\\
\end{align} 
$$

As for the broken arrows, this looks somewhat ugly, but it works:

- `\ce{\bcancel{->}\cancel{->}\xcancel{->}}`: $\ce{\bcancel{->}\cancel{->}\xcancel{->}}$
- `\ce{\xcancel{<=>}\xcancel{->}\xcancel{<-}}`: $\ce{\xcancel{<=>}\xcancel{->}\xcancel{<-}}$

A different possibility is to just use `nrightarrow`, but the arrow looks rather odd (too small) compared to the others in chem mode and harpoons do not even exist

- `\nrightarrow\ce{->}`:  $\nrightarrow\ce{->}$
- `\nleftarrow\ce{<-}`: $\nleftarrow\ce{<-}$
- `\nleftrightarrow\ce{<->}`: $\nleftrightarrow\ce{<->}$
- `\nrightleftharpoons\rightleftharpoons\ce{<=>}`: $\nrightleftharpoons\rightleftharpoons\ce{<=>}$

Basically my idea is to define an addendum like `\not` which can be used like `\not=` or `\not\in` in $\not=$ or $\not\in$.

The following snipped makes use of of `rlap`, which produces a box of zero size and typesets the following element right of it.

- `\ce{\rlap{~~/\!/}->}`: $\ce{\rlap{~~/\!/}->}$

Now it is much more convenient to have a command handy, that is why we can define it via `\def\nnot{\rlap{~~/\!/}}`, we can even add colour via `\def\nnot{\color{red}{\rlap{~~/\!/}}}` $\def\nnot{\color{red}{\rlap{~~/\!/}}}$ and now we can use it in an equation:

- `\ce{c \nnot-> d}`: $\ce{c \nnot-> d}$
- `\ce{c \nnot<-> d}`: $\ce{c \nnot<-> d}$
- `\ce{c \nnot<=> d}`: $\ce{c \nnot<=> d}$

I admit, this is nowhere near an ideal solution, but since mhchem does not currently provide a feature for this I guess this is the best way to use it.

Lastly, I would like to second the demand on physics.se:
https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/siunitx-latex-package

<s>But there seem to be not much efforts about that.</s>
There is an official [feature request](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/447) by our own Manishearth. And it seems to be moving forward.

Comment: I absolutely second the demand for `siunitx`!

Comment: @Klaus Unfortunately there is not much we can do to get that rolling, unless you know how to reimplement it into mathjax :/

Comment: Then we have to live without if for the time being. But it seems that  Joseph Wright, the author of `siunitx` is aware of the demand and [indicated](http://www.texdev.net/2014/09/18/reworking-and-exposing-siunitx-internals/) that things might get easier with `siunitx v3`.

Comment: Another way is to simply use the unicode letter for the cancel effect: `\cancel{→}`