# Is a package (e.g., \require {cancel}) still needed for a diagonal strikeout in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

This post, from six years ago, indicates a diagonal strikeout (e.g., for unit cancellation) can be done by calling the  \require {cancel} package:
[Additions to MathJax/mhchem: Cancel, Broken Arrows; SI units](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/additions-to-mathjax-mhchem-cancel-broken-arrows-si-units)

Can a diagonal strikeout now be done without a package, or is a package still required?

Note: I'm not asking if \cancel still requires a package; it does.  I'm asking if there is currently any way of implementing a diagonal strikeout without needing a package.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't see the point to reimplement something that has already an approved and distributed package, but I do not know how the Mathjax Developer community thinks.

In any case, Stack Exchange uses the (a bit) dated version 2.7.5 from 2018. You can find the releases and change log on [GitHub](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/releases).
For the MathJax 2.7.1 version you can find all available commands here: https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm
And that is pretty much the same as it is possibly available in the version Stack Exchange uses.

According to the documentation there was a rewrite of the core with publication of MathJax 3.0, so maybe they have included it, but I doubt it very much. Packages, or plugins, or extensions are quite common in software development; if it was not included in the core, it probably has a very good reason.

TL;DR: I don't expect that (diagonal) strikeout can be done without a package.

Comment: Sorry if my post wasn't clear; I've edited it to make it more explicit.  I wasn't asking if  \cancel still requires a package—it obviously does.  Instead, I was wondering if creating a strikeout still requires a package.  I.e., I was wondering whether there is now some new built-in (no package call required) command in MathJax that creates a diagonal strikeout.